# Cannot access db when running code from Interactive Console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
# main.py

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
from shared.database import db
from src import controllers
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, allow_headers='Content-Type')

app.register_blueprint(controllers.api)

if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+gaerdbms:///gaiapro_api_dev?instance=dev-gaiapro-api:gaiapro-sql'
else:
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://root@127.0.0.1/gaiapro_api_dev'
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

db.init_app(app)

# shared/database.py

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

# src/controllers/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
from src import models
from src import views
from shared.helpers import *

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/test')
def test():
  ...

# shared/helpers.py

from flask import jsonify, request, abort, make_response
from shared.database import db

def some_method():
    ...
    db.session.commit() # Can access db normally from here

# src/models/__init__.py

from shared.database import db

class Client(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

I am developing for GAE (Google App Engine). Basically what I want is to test my models in the *Interactive Console* from inside the *Admin Server* of _dev_appserver.py_.

I have tried to run the following code from the *Interactive Console*:

```
from main import *
from src import models
print models.Client.query.get(1)
```

The result was:

**RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context**

If I try just to print the *db* variable in this context, the result is: SQLAlchemy engine=None

I don't know what I am doing wrong. My code runs normally on the browser, but I cannot get it to work from the *Interactive Console*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to be in an [app context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/appcontext/) (or a request context) to access application bound objects.

An easy way to achieve this is to use [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which provides a shell command that sets up the application for you.  Or use [Flask's integration with Click](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#cli) if you are using the development version.

To just get it working immediately, set up the context yourself:

```
ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()
# do stuff
ctx.pop()
# quit
```

You can also use a context in a `with` block:

```
with app.app_context():
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

Use flask shell instead of default python interpreter

```
$ flask shell
$ from yourappname import db
$ db     # this will print your connection string
$ db.create_all()
```

Comment: This worked for me as my flask app has had configured database parameters separately